# ASP.NET Core how to deal with an AdalClaimChallengeException when requesting additional resources

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In the Azure Active Directory I've created an app registration for, 2 factor auth is enabled. For a subset of users there is an `AdalClaimChallengeException` thrown stating that user intervention is required:

> AADSTS50079: The user is required to use multi-factor authentication

The exception has a claims value that looks like this:

```
{
  "access_token": {
    "capolids": {
      "essential": true,
      "values": ["<GUID>"]
    }
  }
}
```

The [Azure AD documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-conditional-access-developer) suggests that

> The claims challenge is inside the WWW-Authenticate header, which can be parsed to extract the claims parameter for the next request. **Once it's appended to the new request, Azure AD knows to evaluate the conditional access policy** when signing in the user and the app is now in compliance with the conditional access policy

and

> In our Web API 1, we catch the error error=interaction_required, and send back the claims challenge to the desktop app. At that point, the desktop app can make a new acquireToken() call and **append the claimschallenge as an extra query string parameter**. This new request requires the user to do multi-factor authentication and then send this new token back to Web API 1 and complete the on-behalf-of flow.

I'm confused about how to do this in an MVC app. The middleware component is all set up to make the request, I can catch the exception in the `OnAuthenticationFailed` method but how do I deal with the token?

```
services.AddOpenIdConnect(opts => {
    Configuration.GetSection("Authentication")
    .Bind(opts);

    opts.ClientSecret = aadClientSecret.Value;

    opts.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents {
        OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async ctx => {
            HttpRequest request = ctx.HttpContext.Request;

            //We need to also specify the redirect URL used
            string currentUri = UriHelper
                .BuildAbsolute(request.Scheme, request.Host, request.PathBase, request.Path);

            //Credentials for app itself
            var credential = new ClientCredential(ctx.Options.ClientId, ctx.Options.ClientSecret);

            //Construct token cache
            ITokenCacheFactory cacheFactory = 
                ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenCacheFactory>();
            TokenCache cache = cacheFactory.CreateForUser(ctx.Principal);

            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ctx.Options.Authority, cache);

            //Get token for Microsoft Graph API using the authorization code
            string resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
            AuthenticationResult result = 
                await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                    ctx.ProtocolMessage.Code, new Uri(currentUri), credential, resource);

            //Tell the OIDC middleware we got the tokens, it doesn't need to do anything
            ctx.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
        },
        OnAuthenticationFailed = async ctx => {
            var adalException = ctx.Exception as AdalClaimChallengeException;
            if (adalException != null) {
                HttpRequest request = ctx.HttpContext.Request;
                var claims = adalException.Claims;
                string currentUri = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(request.Scheme, request.Host, request.PathBase, request.Path);
                //Credentials for app itself
                var credential = new ClientCredential(ctx.Options.ClientId, ctx.Options.ClientSecret);

                // there is no user, how do I get their cache?
                var cache = new TokenCache();

                var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ctx.Options.Authority, cache);
                var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", credential);
                // now what?
            }
        }
```